# How to read information from .xml files

Tags: android, xml

My Xml file is like this ->

```
    <Lang>

  <Setting>

    <DisplayIndex>6</DisplayIndex>

    <Visible>True</Visible>

    <Width>289</Width>

  </Setting>

  <Variable ID="1" Name="a">word1</Variable>

  <Variable ID="2" Name="b">word2</Variable>

  <Variable ID="3" Name="c">word3</Variable>

  ...

  </Lang>
```

I want to get ID(or name)and value from it.

1.Where can I put my .xml file?

2.How to get ID(or name)and value from .xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your XML in **assets** folder.
2. I suggest using **JDOM XML Parser** - http://www.jdom.org/
   It would be something like this:

   ```
   Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
   Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
   List list = rootNode.getChildren("Variable");
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      Element node = (Element) list.get(i);
      String id = node.getAttributeValue("ID");
      String value = node.getText();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this](http://xelsoft.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/xml-parsing-android-java/) tutorial to parse `XML` data. The tutorial reads the data from a file inside the sdcard of the device. You can place your `XML` file in the `sdcard` or `raw` folder of the project.

If the `XML` file is in the raw folder of the project then you have to get the `InputSource` like this

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourxmlfile));
```

and document should read the file from `byteStream`

```
Document doc=db.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));
```